# AG-Grid: Export the current rendered grid except two specific columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have two specific columns in my grid. I purposely made sure these columns can not be hidden or moved and I want them to stay like that. The issue is that I want to continue to export the grid as it is currently rendered, but without including the 2 specific columns. How do I do that?

I considered using columnKeys and passing it the gridDescriptor while specifying that those 2 specific columns cannot be exported. Issue is that upon doing so, now the grid will only export based off what the gridDescriptor is and not the current rendering of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you're asking too much of the grid component.

Don't forget that you (presumably) have data that's backing the grid.
It should be fairly easy write code to export whatever you want out of your backing data, instead of trying to get the grid to do it for you.

Comment: Due to code complications its not as easy. I really just want to know if AGgrid has something built in for this scenario.